# Vim UltiSnips for python not working

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I can't figure it out. I have installed the [UltiSnips plugin](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). I followed all the instructions on setting it up. I added this into my `.vimrc` file but it's not working:

```
" Track the engine.
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

I checked that <kbd>Tab</kbd> is not used anywhere in the rest of my `.vimrc` file. When I type `cl` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing happens. However, I am expecting it to offer me insert snippet for the python class.

This is the list of plugin I am using:

```
ctrlp
jedi-vim
SumpylFold
ultisnips
vim-airline
vim-airline-themes
vim-fugitive
Vundle
indentpython
nerdtree
vim-nerdtree-tabs
syntastic
vim-flake8
```

What am I missing here? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of this line in UtliSnips documentation:

> UltiSnips comes without snippets. The default snippets can be found here: https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets

UltiSnips is just an engine, you need to install/create own snippets. I use those recommended `vim-snippets` and they work like a charm.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought it would work out of the box ))).

Comment: Do you know how to add snippets from vim-snippets into UltiSnips? There is no clear information about that. I also assumed according to the installation instructions that UltiSnips will use the snippets from vim-snippets directory in ~/.vim/bundle.

Comment: It should use them. I use `pathogen` and only thing I did was to clone `vim-snippets` to `~/.vim/bundle`. According to UltiSnips documentation: `UltiSnips will search each 'runtimepath' directory for the subdirectory names
defined in g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories in the order they are defined.` So check if `vim-snippets` and `UltiSnips` are in the output of `:scriptnames` and/or `:set rtp?`

Comment: I added this line from the documentation of UltiSnips `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]` to the `.vimrc` file and it's working fine now. It wasn't obvious in my case, though.